# Regular expression for (19,6)

Tags: regex

Trying to write a RegEx function to not allow anything saved to my database that is not a decimal of (19,6)

So 9.999 would work where 68.1234557 would fail. 
Also need 1234567890123456789.1 to fail as well. Sense its out of 19 places.

Also supports negatives

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: So `a < x < b` should be possible to implement using regex?

Comment: A regex in what language (bash, python, Ruby, ...)? They do vary a little...

Comment: Please post some code. You're expected to attempt a solution yourself before posting a question; this is not a site where you can post a description of a problem and wait for solutions to roll in, having done no work yourself.

Comment: I have tried to use \d{,13}(\.\d({,6})? but when I try to use this on a regex tester. It's showing that values such as 9 aren't allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
^[+-]?\d{,13}(\.\d{,6})?$
```

This will match:

- The start of the string (`^`)
- An optional plus or minus sign (a literal `+` or `-`)
- Zero to 13 digits (19 - 6)
- An optional group of:

  - A literal `.`
  - Zero to 6 digits
- The end of the string (`$`)

The start / end anchors are there to prohibit additional characters before or after the matched substring.

Comment: Would match a 25 digit number though. I think he wants 19 digits maximum, with the decimal being up to 6 digits.

Comment: @TyrantWave You're right. The number of digits to the right of the decimal is fixed, so there can only be 13 (19 - 6) digits to the left of the decimal.

Comment: This wouldn't match a number with 16 digits on the left of the decimal and 2 on the right.

Comment: @interjay that's correct `DECIMAL` is a fixed precision data type (at least in MS SQL, and I'm pretty sure in most other SQL engines). That means the total digits is 19, 6 of which are to the right of the decimal, and 13 (19-6) of which are to the left. [See this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/433dc/6/0).

Answer (score 1):

```
^\d{,19}(\.\d{,6})?$
```

If you need the decimal to be required:

```
^\d{,19}\.\d{1,6}$
```

Answer (score 1):

How about : `^(?=^.{1,19}$)\d+(?:\.\d{1,6})?$`

**explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^(?=^.{1,19}$)\d+(?:\.\d{1,6})?$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .{1,19}                  any character except \n (between 1 and
                             19 times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{1,6}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 6 times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

A perl script to test it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $re = qr~^(?=^.{1,19}$)\d+(?:\.\d{1,6})?$~;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    say /$re/ ? "OK : $_" : "KO : $_";
}
__DATA__
9.999
123456.123456
68.1234557
1234567890123456789.1
```

**output:**

```
OK : 9.999
OK : 123456.123456
KO : 68.1234557
KO : 1234567890123456789.1
```